# Xamarin Forms listview inside listview

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, nested

I'm trying to make a listview inside a listview(nested listview) anyone can help? Thanks.

something like this:

[image: nested listview]

Comment: Looks like you need a custom control here, grid or stacklayout with a bindable source property.

Comment: Don't nest a listview inside a listview. This is the worst possible practise. Create a control.

Comment: can you share some code plz for a custom one? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested listview is a general bad practice in Xamarin because you cannot predict which one will get the gesture.

However, you can try using grouping options or can give a try to this [Expandable ListView](http://www.compliancestudio.io/blog/xamarin-forms-expandable-listview).

Another way to solve this is to open a new page once you click on the first list view items and then display the second listview in a second page.

Happy coding,

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to have a nested list view in Xamarin Forms. However it is possible by using custom renders.

You can create a repeater view which can be used inside the list view. Follow the link for the detailed explanation on creating a Repeater view.

[RepeaterView](https://depblog.weblogs.us/2017/09/24/xamarin-forms-repeaterview/)

Comment: I tried that but the problem is that when I try to use the GroupHeaderTemplate and the ItemTemplate together the binding won't work for both